# Pandoc converter : standalone : convert to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, pandoc, pypandoc

I want to know how to use Pandoc in standalone command line manner, to convert existing Excel reports in .xlsx format to PDF.

Hard to find examples on this.

And wondering if it has API interface with Python, to be able to embed this in Python.

Comment: You cannot do this with pandoc alone, xlsx is not a supported format. You could try using  something like libre office calc on the command line to convert to HTML, the result of which could then be passed to pandoc. Not sure how good the end-result would be though.

Comment: Hi, because the pandoc , website says that it is a universal converter, and shows it can handle many permutations of input formats to output formats, its seems like it can be done. Another person on a blog some how fed in excel into Rmarkdown and generated Word doc/PDF.

Comment: I don't want to have a dependency of having like a full fledged suite of some Office software. Do you know of some other library that can convert XLSX to PDF without having a dependency on an office suite. And this will be put on a server, like Ubuntu.

Comment: if you can export to csv, you can use e.g. https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable

Comment: Hi, my excel files can have many things, like Charts, Pivot Tables, Shapes, ... , all kinds of things. SO I need something to handle this which means I can't convert this to CSV.

Comment: SO really need an app that can cover an Excel report that has all things to PDF. So that is the goal.

Comment: Also if this app was a command line app that can interface with Python or Java, that would good so that one could run this on either Windows or Linux platforms.

Comment: You have quite a lot of and very specific requirements.  I don't think there is any one toole that does what you want, but on the off chance that there is, you could try asking here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/